# Entity persistence using Composite/Dependent primary key is failing

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

Saving an Entity along with a Child Entity which has Composite keys is failing in Spring Boot 3.1 (with Spring Data JPA Starter). I have three Entities named `Invoice`, `Product` & `InvoiceItem`. InvoiceItem doesn't have its own unique key, instead it uses a composite key of `invoice_id`, `product_id`. Now I'm using `EmbeddedId` technique to model this in my application. But when I'm saving my first Invoice, I get  the following error

```
Could not set value of type [java.lang.Long] : `info.fareez.goldin.entities.embeddables.InvoiceItemId.invoiceId` (setter)
```

I have checked all the fields and compared with the JPA Spec and examples [here](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/persistence/3.0/jakarta-persistence-spec-3.0.html#a149). Still I'm unable to solve this.

Note: I also tried with @IdClass technique, and it has repeated field names in IdClass and Entity, so I wanted to solve it with EmbeddedId

Here is the code,

**Invoice:**

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Invoice {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id", nullable = true)
    private Customer customer;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "invoice", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private List<InvoiceItem> invoiceItems;

    private Date timestamp;

    private double price;
}
```

**Product**

```java
@Builder
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Setter
@Getter
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String code;

    private String name;

    private double purity;

    private double weight;

    private int stock;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product")
    private List<InventoryTransaction> inventoryTransactions;

}
```

**InvoiceItem**

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Embeddable
public class InvoiceItemId {
    private Long invoiceId;
    private Long productId;
}

@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class InvoiceItem {

    @EmbeddedId
    private InvoiceItemId invoiceItemId;

    @MapsId("invoiceId")
    @ManyToOne
    private Invoice invoice;

    @MapsId("productId")
    @OneToOne
    private Product product;

    private Double price;
}
```

And when I tried to save a new Invoice with the following code

```
List<InvoiceItem> invoiceItems = new ArrayList<>();

var invoice = Invoice.builder()
                 .customer(customer)
                 .timestamp(new Date()).build();

for (var itemDto : invoiceRequest.getInvoiceItems()) {
  // prepare invoice items here
  invoiceItems.add(
        InvoiceItem.builder()
            .invoice(invoice)
            .product(product.toProduct())
            // other fields
            .build())
}

invoice.setInvoiceItems(invoiceItems);
invoice.setPrice(totalPrice);

invoiceRepository.save(invoice);
```

I get the following error

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: Could not set value of type [java.lang.Long] : `info.fareez.goldin.entities.embeddables.InvoiceItemId.invoiceId` (setter)
    at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.SetterFieldImpl.set(SetterFieldImpl.java:81) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Component$ValueGenerationPlan.execute(Component.java:538) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.id.CompositeNestedGeneratedValueGenerator.generate(CompositeNestedGeneratedValueGenerator.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:114) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:184) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:129) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:118) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:779) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:727) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$7.cascade(CascadingActions.java:301) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$7.cascade(CascadingActions.java:291) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:513) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:434) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:220) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:547) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:477) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:437) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:220) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:153) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeAfterSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:474) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:298) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:192) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:184) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:129) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:53) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:737) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:721) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:311) ~[spring-orm-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at jdk.proxy3/jdk.proxy3.$Proxy122.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:613) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:288) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:136) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:120) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:516) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:285) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:628) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:168) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:143) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:77) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:391) ~[spring-tx-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    ... 35 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "Object.getClass()" because "o" is null
```

Comment: Please add the definition of InvoiceItemId.

Comment: @JohnWilliams done. Thanks for highlighting it

Answer (score 0):

I found that the following worked.

Sadly I had to first persist the `Invoice` and separately persist the `InvoiceItems` so that I had access to the `invoiceId`. Also the lombok Builder did not populate the `@EmbeddedId` properly.

```
List<InvoiceItem> invoiceItems = new ArrayList<>();

var invoice = Invoice.builder()
                 .customer(customer)
                 .timestamp(new Date()).build();
        
invoice = invoiceRepository.save(invoice); // to get the invoiceId


for (var itemDto : invoiceRequest.getInvoiceItems()) {
  // prepare invoice items here
    InvoiceItemId invoiceItemId = new InvoiceItemId(invoice.getId(), product.getId());
    InvoiceItem invoiceItem = new InvoiceItem(invoiceItemId , invoice, product, price );

  invoiceItems.add(
        invoiceItem )
}

invoice.setInvoiceItems(invoiceItems);
invoice.setPrice(totalPrice);

invoiceRepository.save(invoice);
```

I also had to set `invoiceItems` to `CascadeType.ALL`

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "invoice", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<InvoiceItem> invoiceItems;
```